# When handling XMLHttpRequest in Nodejs proxy server, I've already call "res.end()", but client's behavior seems can't get my res and timeout finally

Tags: node.js, proxy, xmlhttprequest, timeout

I have a question.
In my Nodejs proxy server, from debug log, I can see I've already handled the request, send its correct response and call "res.end()" to end this request. And this request is XMLHttpRequest.

And from Chrome's developer tool, I can see that this request has got correct response from my Nodejs https server, and its status code is 200 OK.

But from the web UI, the client seems still waiting for my response because its image is always turning over and over, and seems to time out finally. Like the screenshot below.

[image]

Can anyone give me some advice? I don't understand why the client can't get my response data. And this request is XMLHttpRequest.Thanks very much.

Comment: It would be better if you write your code with the question in order to explain your question further. With this information it is difficult to figure out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. Because I need to response to long poll request immediately. If don't, the client will cancle the request or timeout